# runuser error handling

Tags: shell-script

We use `runuser` inside some of our deployment scripts.  In looking at the scripts I'm wondering how the error handling would work if any of the commands within the `runuser` steps errors out.  In attempting to solve this myself, I haven't come up with any definitive other than using `&&` as such:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "- next"
# this is what we're currently doing, which appears to not handle errors
runuser -l $USER -c "echo cmd2; ls non-existant-file; echo done";
echo "  exit code $?"

echo "- next2"
# best solution I've come up with so far
runuser -l $USER -c "echo cmd2 && ls non-existant-file && echo done";
echo "  exit code $?"

echo "- finish"
```

Any suggestions for how to better address this issue?  Given some of the individual commands within the `runuser` script can get pretty involved (i.e. conditionals and the like), I'm hoping to find a more-elegant/obvious way to handle any errors.

Another thought is to do something like this:

```
runuser -l $USER -c "echo cmd2 && ls non-existant-file && echo done" || exit 1
```